Airflow - K8s- Unable to mount HostPath using KubenetesPodOperator
I have a ADF's Airflow managed instance provisioned. And, I'm trying to schedule a DAG.
In this DAG, I'm trying to run a shell script which is present in the HOSTPATH "/opt/airflow/dags" using KubernetesPodOperator. The shell script will submit some kubectl commands to a k8s cluster. However the pod is not getting started on k8s.
dag.py:
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.providers.cncf.kubernetes.operators.kubernetes_pod import KubernetesPodOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from kubernetes.client import models as k8s

# Define your default_args and DAG
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(1970, 1, 1),
    'retries': 0,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
}

dag = DAG(
    'test_operations_dag',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='DAG for test Operations',
    #schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1),
    schedule_interval=None,
    concurrency=80,
)

# Correct instantiation using V1HostPathVolumeSource
host_path_volume_source = k8s.V1HostPathVolumeSource(
    path="/opt/airflow/dags",
    type='Directory'  # optional: specify the type of the hostPath
)

volume = k8s.V1Volume(
    name="dags",
    host_path=host_path_volume_source
)

volume_mounts = [
    k8s.V1VolumeMount(
        mount_path="/dags", name="dags"
    )
]

status_task = KubernetesPodOperator(
    task_id=f'status-task-vbuv',
    namespace="spark-apps",
    image="bitnami/kubectl:latest",
    cmds=["sh", "-c"],
    arguments=[
        f"cp /dags/sparkapplication_spark-pi-fixed2.sh /tmp/sparkapplication_spark-pi-fixed2.sh && chmod +x /tmp/sparkapplication_spark-pi-fixed2.sh && /tmp/sparkapplication_spark-pi-fixed2.sh"
    ],
    service_account_name="airflow-sparkapp",
    get_logs=True,
    kubernetes_conn_id="k8s-airflow",
    dag=dag,
    volumes=[volume],
    volume_mounts=volume_mounts,
)      
# Set up dependencies
status_task

Error in dag log:
[2024-04-18, 05:01:52 UTC] {pod_manager.py:313} WARNING - Pod not yet started: status-task-vbuv-8h4po563
[2024-04-18, 05:01:52 UTC] {pod.py:726} INFO - Deleting pod: status-task-vbuv-8h4po563
[2024-04-18, 05:01:52 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1824} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/cncf/kubernetes/operators/pod.py", line 551, in execute_sync
    self.await_pod_start(pod=self.pod)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/cncf/kubernetes/operators/pod.py", line 513, in await_pod_start
    self.pod_manager.await_pod_start(pod=pod, startup_timeout=self.startup_timeout_seconds)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/cncf/kubernetes/utils/pod_manager.py", line 320, in await_pod_start
    raise PodLaunchFailedException(msg)
airflow.providers.cncf.kubernetes.utils.pod_manager.PodLaunchFailedE


I don't think you actually want a HostPathVolumeSource.  How would you ensure identical content is available at the same non-container directory on every node in the cluster, including nodes that might get dynamically added via the cluster autoscaler?

Actually, my scripts are present in /opt/airflow/dags of all airflow workers. And, I want the same script to be run using KubernetesPodOperator on a different K8s cluster. Hence, I thought of mounting the HostPath(I mean the airflow worker's HostPath) on the pod which is running on a different k8s cluster.

I see the pod is considering the k8s node on which the pod is running, as the Host. But, I want to get the files from airflow worker.

A hostPath: type volume is always interpreted on the Node the Pod happens to be running on.  Except in some very limited cases (like log collectors running as DaemonSets on every node) you don't want it, because you'll get different content depending on what Node you get scheduled on.

Got it, thanks.
But, how SparkKubernetesOperator is able to access the file "spark-app-with-args-test-merge.yaml" which is on airflow worker(/opt/airflow/dags).?
spark_task = SparkKubernetesOperator(
    task_id='spark-task-test',
    trigger_rule="all_success",
    depends_on_past=False,
    retries=0,
    application_file="spark-app-with-args-test-merge.yaml", 
    kubernetes_conn_id="k8s-airflow",
    namespace="spark-apps",
    api_group="sparkoperator.k8s.io",
    api_version="v1beta2",
    do_xcom_push=True,
    dag=dag)

